# Swift viewWillAppear not being called after dismissing view controller

Tags: ios, swift, viewwillappear, viewcontroller-lifecyle

I am presenting a view controller from a view controller called HomeController like so:

```
let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginController") as! LoginController

let navigationController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)

present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In the presented view controller LoginController at some point gets dismissed:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But when it comes back to HomeController it is not calling viewWillAppear, I really need to check on condition on HomeController when it comes back to it, So how can I call viewWillAppear when LoginController dismisses the view?

Comment: If the presentation is not over full screen or if the animation is custom, then the appearance methods are not called on the underlying controller.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to set the correct [presentationStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle). If you want that your presentedController will be fullScreen and call it the previous viewWillAppear, then you can use "**.fullScreen**"

```
let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginController") as! LoginController

let navigationController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)

navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You can click on the segue in the storyboard and under the Attributes Inspector, change the Presentation to Full Screen.  For me, it is easier than writing the code.

Comment: I know this is an old question but still relevant to keep it fresh. I had a issue with not ALL my segues being fullscreen modal presentation. It was driving me crazy but it makes sense. All view controllers presented modally must be full screen otherwise view will appear will not be called at all. Even if you miss one, the last view when dismissed to root, will not call view will appear.

Comment: I works. Setting by code helped me to check the solution, also you can change it from IB in the Navigation Controller > Attributes Inspector.

Answer (score 17):

If presented viewController is half screen then you will have to Call the viewWillAppear of presenting viewController manually in side presented view controller's viewWillDisappear.
Add following code to your Presented view controller.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    presentingViewController?.viewWillDisappear(true)
}    

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    presentingViewController?.viewWillAppear(true)
}
```

Note: you must have to call 'presentingViewController?.viewWillDisappear(true)' to get your Presenting view controllers **viewWillAppear** execute everytime.

Comment: This solution throws errors in the console and break animation in UINavigationControllers - see my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74618304/158548

Comment: Now The viewDidAppear is stop working on other views.

Answer (score 9):

Changing presentation style to .fullScreen works but changes the appearance of the presented view Controller. If u want to avoid that u can override the viewWillDisappear method in the presented viewcontroller and inside it add `presentingViewController?.viewWillAppear(true)`.

Example:

```
 class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {
 
      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          
          //put the presenting action wherever you want

          let vc = ViewControllerB()
          navigationController.present(vc, animated: true)
      }

      override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
           super.viewWillAppear(animated) 
           //refresh Whatever 
      }
 }

 class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {
 
      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
      }

      override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
          super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

          //this will call the viewWillAppear method from ViewControllerA  

          presentingViewController?.viewWillAppear(true)
      }
 }
```

Comment: Good but only works the first time

Comment: It's also worth noting with this approach that if ViewControllerB presents ViewControllerC, then the viewWillDisappear() method is also called when ViewControllerC appears, which might not be desirable.

Comment: This solution throws errors in the console and break animation in UINavigationControllers - see my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74618304/158548

Answer (score 4):

None of these solutions seemed satisfactory, and indeed the solutions that suggested calling `presentingViewController?.viewWillAppear(true)` actually break animations in navigations controllers and throws warnings from UIKit in the console.

The correct way is to use the built in methods in UIKit, as suggested by the warnings! These will call all the respective methods `viewWill`/`DidAppear` in the presenting class.

Note I have an if statement checking if the `modelPresentationStyle` is equal to `pageSheet` as this is the value that recent releases of iOS set the default presentation style to. We do not want to interfere with other presentation styles as they may already call `viewWill`/`DidAppear` and it should not be called twice.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // view lifecycle events are not passed down to the presentingViewController if in pageSheet style (and maybe others)
    if modalPresentationStyle == .pageSheet {
        presentingViewController?.beginAppearanceTransition(false, animated: animated)
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // view lifecycle events are not passed down to the presentingViewController if in pageSheet style (and maybe others)
    if modalPresentationStyle == .pageSheet {
        presentingViewController?.endAppearanceTransition()
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    // view lifecycle events are not passed down to the presentingViewController if in pageSheet style (and maybe others)
    if modalPresentationStyle == .pageSheet {
        presentingViewController?.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: animated)
    }
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    // view lifecycle events are not passed down to the presentingViewController if in pageSheet style (and maybe others)
    if modalPresentationStyle == .pageSheet {
        presentingViewController?.endAppearanceTransition()
    }
}
```

Comment: `presentingViewController` in `viewDidDisappear` always nil. you may add `private weak var presentingViewControllerBeforeDisappear: UIViewController?`, and set `presentingViewControllerBeforeDisappear = presentingViewController` before `presentingViewController?.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: animated)` in `viewWillDisappear`, and then set `presentingViewControllerBeforeDisappear?.endAppearanceTransition()` in `viewDidDisappear`

Comment: If you present a view controller inside a navigation controller, and then you push a new view controller to this presented navigation stack, presentingViewController will get viewWillAppear call, which is not correct

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 13 , if you are presenting a view controller and when you are coming back viewWillAppear doesn't get called . 
   I have changed it from present to push view controller and methods are getting called now .

Comment: When u navigate from VC1 to VC2 , u must have written present view controller . just change it to push

Comment: one more way is to change the presentation style.:    vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

Comment: I think I understand you, but there is no push method, do I need to use some another protocol beside UIViewController for this?

Comment: How are u navigating to another view controller ?

Comment: @SateeshPasala if you navigate from VC1 to VC2 with modal presentation mode ?

Comment: Then you have to set it to full screen mode. like this

VC2.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5. Work for me. Maybe all forget about delegate.

First Controller

```
let calendarVC = CalendarVC()
calendarVC.delegate = self
calendarVC.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
present(calendarVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Present controller

Add Delegate ........

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        delegate?.closeState()
 }
```

Work when swipe and dismiss button. Have a good day )